# db connecting in php

Tags: php, constructor

I have such code, with downloaded from i-net class for db.
I'm interested, how i can do connecting in constructor, so that i will not connect db in each method as i do now. but i get a lot of error, here is code:

```
<?php
include_once('mysqldatabase.php');
include_once('mysqlresultset.php');
class Car
{
    public $marka;
    public $model;
    public $engineVol;
    public $VIN;
    public $engineType;
    public $transmission;
    public $bodyType;
    public $other;
    public $clientCode;
    public $code;

    public function __construct()
    {


    }

    public function viewCar($id)
    {
        $db = MySqlDatabase::getInstance();
        try {
            $conn = $db->connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'discont');
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        echo "view <br>   ";
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM car Where Code = '.$id.'';
            foreach ($db->iterate($query) as $row) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "~".$row->Marka;
        }
    }

    public function addCar()
    {
        echo "add";
        $db = MySqlDatabase::getInstance();
            try {
            $conn = $db->connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'discont');
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

            $query = "SELECT * FROM car";
        foreach ($db->iterate($query) as $row) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $row->Marka;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

sory for my, maybe, stupid question. but i really don't know how(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class variable `$db`

```
private $db;
```

Move this code from `viewCar()` to the contructor:

```
$this->db = MySqlDatabase::getInstance();
try {
    $conn = $this->db->connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'discont');
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Remove the duplicate code from addCar(), and finally, update references in `viewCar()` and `addCar()` from `$db` to `$this->db`.